# Simple Injector, Function Not Being Intercepted?

Tags: c#, simple-injector, aop, cross-cutting-concerns

I am trying to have a cross cutting concern intercept my calls on my controller but for some reason they aren't being intercepted.

I am basically trying to get the example here to work:
http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/InterceptionExtensions.html

They have some other info in the interception section here too:
http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html

I have a feeling it is because I am not setting up the Container correctly. Could someone show me how I need to change my main to see `"Intercepted!!!"` after the calls on the Controller are made? Also, can someone tell me if the setup for the Container was wrong, and if so, explain my error(s).

**The Code:**

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start");    

    RedisController2 redisController = new RedisController2();    

    Container _container = new Container();
    _container.InterceptWith<MonitoringInterceptor>(type => type == typeof(IRedisController2));
    _container.RegisterSingle<MonitoringInterceptor>();    

    redisController.PrintSomething();
    redisController.PrintOther();    

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

internal class MonitoringInterceptor : IInterceptor
{    

    public MonitoringInterceptor()
    {    

    }    

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();    

        //var decoratedType = invocation.InvocationTarget.GetType();    

        Console.Write("Intercepted!!!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that the *Container* is not creating the *Controller* and therefore cannot intercept calls made to it. Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Start");    

Container _container = new Container();
_container.Register<IRedisController2, RedisController2>(); // 1
_container.InterceptWith<MonitoringInterceptor>(type => 
    type == typeof(IRedisController2));
_container.RegisterSingle<MonitoringInterceptor>();    

IRedisController2 redisController =
    _container.GetInstance<IRedisController2>(); // 2, 3

redisController.PrintSomething();
redisController.PrintOther();    

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Notice that I have:

1. added code to register the *Controller*
2. added code to request an instance of the *Controller* from the *Container*
3. changed the type being created from `RedisController2` to `IRedisController2` (because `IRedisController2` is what has been configured for interception)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `SimpleInjector` is working in the same way as 90% of all IOC containers, it uses `RealProxy` under the covers* (given the signature it is most likely, although completely against the spirit of `SimpleInjector`).

> Note: The Interception extensions code snippets use .NET’s System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy class to generate interception proxies. The RealProxy only allows to proxy interfaces. [[source](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#interception)]

`RealProxy` works with interfaces, due to obvious reason (if you think deeply about it for a while). Even if it could work with a base class, that base class must declare its method as `virtual` for your code to have worked.

Rework your code to use interfaces when calling `RedisController2`, and remove all references to `RedisController2` except at registration.